# How to read Pandas Dataframe column information through string variable iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with columns `'Var_1_Access'`, `'Var_2_Access'`,... `'Var_N_Access'` and there is other information/columns between these columns that I would like to look for. For example:

```
data = pd.read_csv('File')
df = pd.Dataframe(data)
print(df.columns)


Index = (['Var_1', 'Var_1_Access', 'Var_1_comp1', 'Var_1_comp2', 'Var_2', 'Var_2_Access', 'Var_2_comp1', 'Var_2_comp2'], dtype='object')
```

I would like to write a for loop that goes through the range of N and pulls out `'Var_1_Access'` up to `'Var_N_Access'`.

I've tried:

```
Access_Matrix = []
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    Access_Matrix.append(df.f"Var_%i_Access" % i)

Access_Matrix = []
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    Access_Matrix.append(df.Var_{i}_Access)

Access_Matrix = []
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    Access_Matrix.append(df.Var_[i]_Access)
```

These all result in errors. Yes it would be possible to just write them in as N is small, but N will grow large and I really don't want to have to type every variable name in individually, and would rather index it. The end goal is to read the Pandas dataframe information for N variables and have the `Access_Matrix` be of shape `[len(Var_N_Access), N]`. Also, there may be the need to add more information between these specific variable names later, so that is the reason I would like to index it by string variable names vs. column indices and look for a pattern.

I can provide more information if necessary, but I think that this covers the necessary information.

Comment: I apologize for the format, not sure how to change it to an acceptable format so the post reads as two sections of code and three text blocks.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the format. I'll be sure to look back to this post in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with '.' notation, but you should be able to do this in square brackets with a 'f' string.

```
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    Access_Matrix.append(df[f"Var_{i}_Access"])
```

Or, perhaps a better approach would be to build up a list of the column names and extract them into a new dataframe in one go from `df`, e.g.:

```
cols = [f"Var_{i}_Access" for i in range(1, N+1)]
all_cols = df[cols]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm, I'll accept the answer as soon as stack lets me. Thank you!

Comment: I started with that approach but couldn't figure out how to write the correct syntax to pull the data from the dataframe. How would you do it that way?

Comment: I've added some code to do that to the answer. To be honest, the other answer using a regex to filter the dataframe is probably the best approach to achieve the same result in a single command.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas.DataFrame.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

It will filter the columns using regex and produce a filtered version

```
access_df = df.filter(regex=f'Var_\d_Access')
```

For a specific value of `N` or to get until a range,

```
access_df = df.filter(regex=f'Var_[1-{N}]_Access')
```

This method is much more efficient than using a crude loop.